# Typescript Maybe, error about null not being covered

Tags: typescript, option-type

I don't know how to get rid of this error, and I don't know why it talks about null.

Shouldn't the `seo?.breadcrumbs || []` already cover the case where `breadcrumbs` is null?

However in the Intro Propos, if I do `as SEOPostTypeBreadcrumbs[]`, then it fixes the issue, but I feel that it is not the solution.

EDIT: It looks like it complains that items in the array of `breadcrumbs` can be `null`?
This was autogenerated by Wordpress GraphQL tool `graphql-codegen`

```
TS2322: Type 'Maybe<{ __typename?: "SEOPostTypeBreadcrumbs" | undefined; } 
& Pick<SeoPostTypeBreadcrumbs, "text" | "url">>[]' is not assignable to type 'SeoPostTypeBreadcrumbs[]'.   
Type 'Maybe<{ __typename?: "SEOPostTypeBreadcrumbs" | undefined; } & Pick<SeoPostTypeBreadcrumbs, "text" | "url">>' 
is not assignable to type 'SeoPostTypeBreadcrumbs'.     
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SeoPostTypeBreadcrumbs'.  
intro.tsx(28, 5): The expected type comes from property 'breadcrumbs' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntroProps'
```

`seo` type:

```
export type CptNeighborhoodFragment = { __typename: 'CptNeighborhood' } & {
    seo?: Maybe<
        { __typename?: 'PostTypeSEO' } & Pick<
            PostTypeSeo,
            | 'metaDesc'
            | 'metaKeywords'
            | 'metaRobotsNofollow'
            | 'metaRobotsNoindex'
            | 'opengraphAuthor'
            | 'opengraphDescription'
            | 'title'
        > & {
                breadcrumbs?: Maybe<
                    Array<
                        Maybe<
                            { __typename?: 'SEOPostTypeBreadcrumbs' } & Pick<
                                SeoPostTypeBreadcrumbs,
                                'text' | 'url'
                            >
                        >
                    >
                >;
            }
    >;
};
```

Usage:

```
<Intro
    title={seo?.title || ''}
    breadcrumbs={seo?.breadcrumbs || []}
/>
```

Intro Props

```
interface IntroProps {
    title: string;
    breadcrumbs?: SeoPostTypeBreadcrumbs[];
}
```

SeoPostTypeBreadcrumbs

```
export type SeoPostTypeBreadcrumbs = {
    __typename?: 'SEOPostTypeBreadcrumbs';
    text?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
    url?: Maybe<Scalars['String']>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an [avoidOptionals](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript#avoidoptionals) object in your codegen config to prevent nested Maybe wrappers from appearing in the output code

you can also [modify the value of the Maybe type](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript#avoidoptionals) from `T | null` (default) to whatever you'd like it to be; `T | null | undefined`, maybe.